# How to Increment variable in html / php

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to increment variable in html .. the variable is declared in php and I need to increment it in php ... I write the code bellow :

```
global  $indice_array_contact;
$indice_array_contact=0;
<img src="images/back1.png" onclick='left_clik()'>
<img src="images/back2.png" onclick='right_clik()'>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
     <?php  $indice_array_contact=$indice_array_contact+1; ?>

            function left_clik()
             { document.getElementById("im1").src = "profiles_stored/executive.png";
                 document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = "<?php echo $indice_array_contact ?>";
            <?php  $indice_array_contact=$indice_array_contact+1; ?>
             }


         function right_clik()
         { document.getElementById("im1").src = "profiles_stored/<?php echo $array_contact[0]->profile ?>";        
            document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = "<?php echo $indice_array_contact ?>";
          <?php  $indice_array_contact=$indice_array_contact+1; ?>
         }
```

When I click on the right_click button , the value is 1 ,and when I click on the left_click button , the value is 2 ... but if I click second time on right_click button the value doesn't change to 3. Why?

Comment: You should really change your script tag to `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: and you should explain us, why do you try to use two different functions to increment one value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will never work the way you want it - you are mixing server-side scripting ( php ) with client-side scripting ( javascript ).

What really happens in your example:

1. Your $indice_array_contact is incremented by one during page load on the server
2. Your function left_click() and right_click() receive the value of ( presumably ) 2 in the document.getElementById().innerHTML during page load, as calculated on the server -> this will never change on your already loaded page!
3. You hit a button and trigger either the left_click() or right_click() function -> the innerHTML DOM property receives value of 2, as the server calculated during page load -> this happens each time you execute the function

Try to re-work your implementation with only javascript as it looks you are looking for something that should change without the page being reloaded.

Comment: Thank You @Shadow Walker ,,, it help a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is not necessary for this is it? Shouldn't something like this work:

```
<img src="images/back1.png" onclick='left_clik()'>
<img src="images/back2.png" onclick='right_clik()'>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
    var indice_array_contact = 0
    function left_clik()
     { 
        document.getElementById("im1").src = "profiles_stored/executive.png";
        document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = indice_array_contact;
        indice_array_contact++;
     }


     function right_clik()
     { 
        document.getElementById("im1").src = "profiles_stored/executive.png";
        document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = indice_array_contact;
        indice_array_contact++;
     }
```

Comment: both your functions do the same